# Git grep syntax with square brackets

Tags: regex, git

Why does `git log --grep=\[92\]` match the commit with the following message:

```
Author: Aston, Ben (Foo-UK) <Ben.Aston@foo.co.uk>
Date:   Wed May 23 12:56:23 2012 +0000

[83] Favourites icon addition for release. <BA>


git-tfs-id: [http://fooppp012v:8080/tfs/TFS2010%20Collection]$/Foo/DnR;C210630
```

It seems that the correct regular expression format is not what I think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with `git log --grep=\\[92\\]`. Now you get it, right? :)

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for us:

```
git log --grep='\[92\]'
```